# ASP.NET menus and CSS?

Tags: asp.net, menu, css-selectors

I have the feeling that using Sitemap in ASP.NET is not conducive to CSS. Where do I format a menu to look like CSS can make it look. Where are mu ul and li's?

...Beginner, so forgive me if there right under my nose.

Comment: You're best off with a repeater if you want to control the resulting HTML very finely. I've added examples to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a SiteMap is extremily useful when using it to show Menus and Breadcrums.

You can read some tutorials on how to accomplish this like [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20050531.asp). If you want to **generate pure UL / LI** I suggest you read [this post](http://blogs.sqlxml.org/bryantlikes/archive/2006/02/17/4839.aspx)

There is always the ASP.NET Video tutorial on [How Do I: **Implement Site Navigation** in ASP.NET?](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-192.aspx)

Try, as well use the [**CSS Friendly Adapters**](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/) (that's what they were build for) - there's a [video tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-185.aspx) as well.

*Hope it helps*

Comment: +1 for the CSS Friendly Adapters - these are the way to go if you want to use a more CSS oriented way of doing things - indeed, these are going to be part of the ASP.NET 4.0 framework, rather than a seperate download.

Comment: a long time waiting feature :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a CSS menu with ul's and li's ? There is nothing in ASP.NET that says you have to use web controls, normal HTML works just as well (probably better).

Comment: I was slightly concerned that if I used just CSS then I would be missing out on the simplicity of the SiteMap functionality - obviously I'm not.

I think I'll just try it with CSS.

Comment: The problem with WebForm's controls normally is they are simple to do simple things, hard to do slightly less simple things. Downright frustrating to do complicated things.

Answer (score 1):

For complete control over a menu you could use a Repeater and bind it to your Web.SiteMap.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MenuRepeater" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <li>
      <a href='<%#Eval("url")%>'><%#Eval("Title")%></a>
    </li>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

If you're looking to do CSS dropdown menus then simply add in a nested Repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MenuRepeater" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <li>
      <a href='<%#Eval("url")%>'><%#Eval("Title")%></a>
      <ul>
        <asp:Repeater ID="DropDownRepeater" DataSource='<%#Container.DataItem.ChildNodes()%>' runat="server">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
              <a href='<%#Eval("url")%>'><%#Eval("Title")%></a>
            </li>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

So you'll get the CSS menus you want and still be using your Web.SiteMap.

Comment: Will only get you two levels though. Better to write some recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the SiteMapDataSource with a Repeater tu produce a standard `<ul><li>` menu list. You can even add your own attributes to the web.sitemap file, e.g. to specify an image for the menu item...

Answer (score 0):

teknohippy's advice on using a repeater is great!

However, the line

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="DropDownRepeater" DataSource='<%#Container.DataItem.ChildNodes()%>' runat="server">
```

is incorrect.  It needs to be

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# ((SiteMapNode) Container.DataItem).ChildNodes %>'>
```

in order to work.

Details are available in this excellent tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx